# Help me solve $291x\equiv1\pmod {23}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I don't know how to solve this equation:
$$291x\equiv1\pmod {23}\in \mathbb Z^+$$
Please help me.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint: $291\equiv 15 \pmod {23}$.  If all else fails, just try all $23$ possibilities to find the inverse.

Comment: We can use WolframAlpha to give us [the answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=291x%3D1mod23)

Comment: @lulu No need to try; $23$ is a prime, so $15^{21}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $15$.

Comment: $$x=20$$ since $$291\cdot 20\equiv 1 \mod 23$$

Comment: Hmmm, @brainhost  I see you've made a habit of posting homework questions, and adding only  "I don't know how .... " and/or  "Please help me...".  It's time you review (or read for the first time): [How to Ask a Good Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Maybe 20 is the lowest value satisfying the equation but there are infinitely many.

Comment: @lioness99a It's not worth having an edit war over a question of this quality, so I'm not planning to try to "fix" this, but $291x\equiv1\pmod {23}\in \mathbb Z^+$ is not any kind of mathematical sentence I've ever seen. I'm not even sure what it would mean, formally. What does it say is an element of $\mathbb Z^+$? The number $1$? The number $23$? The entire equation?

Answer (score 5):

Apply Euclid's Algorithm to $291$ and $23$,

\begin{align}
291 & =12(23)+15 \\
23 & =15+8\\
15 & =8+7\\
8 & =7+1\\
\end{align}
So we have $\gcd(291,23)=1$, and 
\begin{align}
1& =8-7\\
&=8-(15-8)\\
&=2(8)-15\\
&=2(23-15)-15\\
&=2(23)-3(15)\\
&=2(23)-3(291-23\times12)\\
&=38(23)-3(291)
\end{align}
So $-3(291)=1 \mod{23}$

Hence $x=-3 \mod{23}$.

Since $x\in \Bbb Z^+$, then $x=-3+23t$ for $t\in \Bbb Z_{\ge 1}$

Comment: OP has asked for $\mathbb{Z}^+$ so you might want to add just one extra line.

Comment: @IanMiller Thanks for reminding :)

Answer (score 1):

We can reduce the multiplier $\bmod 23$:
$291x\equiv 15x \bmod 23$

Then find the inverse of $15\bmod 23$ :
Note that $15\cdot 3 =45 \equiv -1 \bmod 23$
Thus $15\cdot -3  \equiv15\cdot 20  \equiv 1 \bmod 23$

Therefore
$20\cdot 15x\equiv 20\cdot 1 \bmod 23
\\x\equiv 20 \bmod 23$
(so $x=20+23k, k \in \Bbb Z \ge 0$)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 23\!:\,\ 291\equiv -8,\ $ so $\,\ {-}8x \equiv 1\equiv 24\,\iff\, x\equiv \dfrac{24}{-8}\equiv -3\equiv 20$

Answer (score 0):

Because the numbers are so small, it's not hard to solve for $x$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}
291\equiv15=3\cdot5&\mod 23\\
3\cdot8=24\equiv1&\mod 23\\
5\cdot9=45\equiv-1&\mod23\\
\therefore15(-72)\equiv1&\mod23\\
\therefore15\cdot20\equiv1&\mod 23
\end{align}$$

So $x=20$ satisfies $291x\equiv1$ mod $23$.